# ERROR main com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer null

Tags: hadoop, presto

I am trying to configure presto in my `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (32bit)`, `Java 1.7.0_25`, `Python 2.7.3` .

Won't presto work in 32 bit systems? Please help me overcome this issue.

I am getting the following error.

```
2013-11-14T14:37:54.165+0530    DEBUG   main    com.facebook.presto.hive.RebindSafeMBeanServer  io.airlift.node:name=NodeInfo already bound to io.airlift.node.NodeInfo[io.airlift.node:name=NodeInfo]
2013-11-14T14:37:54.217+0530    DEBUG   main    com.facebook.presto.hive.RebindSafeMBeanServer  io.airlift.http.client:type=AsyncHttpClient,name=ForDiscoveryClient already bound to io.airlift.http.client.netty.NettyAsyncHttpClient[io.airlift.http.client:type=AsyncHttpClient,name=ForDiscoveryClient]
2013-11-14T14:37:54.218+0530    DEBUG   main    com.facebook.presto.hive.RebindSafeMBeanServer  io.airlift.discovery.client:name=ServiceInventory already bound to io.airlift.discovery.client.ServiceInventory[io.airlift.discovery.client:name=ServiceInventory]
2013-11-14T14:37:54.227+0530    **ERROR main    com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer null**
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at com.facebook.presto.hive.HiveClient$$FastClassByGuice$$de77531.newInstance(<generated>) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40) ~[guice-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:60) ~[guice-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85) ~[guice-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254) ~[guice-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46) ~[guice-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031) ~[guice-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40) ~[guice-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65) ~[guice-3.0.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presto requires as 64bit Oracle/OpenJDK Java version 7u6 or higher